# Integration of $f(x)=10x^{20}+2x^{19}+3x^{9}+100x^{2}+20x+98$ what is $F(x)$?

Tags: calculus

How to integrate $$\int\left(10x^{20}+2x^{19}+3x^{9}+100x^{2}+20x+98\right)dx$$
 any hint is welcome.

Comment: Use linearity of the integral and $\int x^n dx = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+\mathrm{const}$.

Comment: Don't get impressed by the long sum or high exponents. Just follow the rule stated above.

Comment: This is definitely not primarily a social site - or rather, it is a social site with parameters. People joke here, but most often in comments, or in ways that do not detract from the question/answer goal of this site.

Comment: I've deleted a bunch of comments. Please keep comments on-topic, and don't edit this question except to add or clarify details.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\int\color{darkmagenta}{10x^{20}}+\color{blue}{2x^{19}}+\color{green}{3x^{9}}+\color{red}{100x^{2}}+\color{fuchsia}{20x}+\color{darkorange}{98}\,\mathrm dx\\ =\color{darkmagenta}{\int10x^{20}}\,\mathrm dx+\color{blue}{\int2x^{19}}\,\mathrm dx+\color{green}{\int3x^{9}}\,\mathrm dx+\color{red}{\int100x^{2}}\,\mathrm dx+\color{fuchsia}{\int20x}\,\mathrm dx+\color{darkorange}{\int98}\,\mathrm dx \\\,\\ =\ldots\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\,\,\,\,\qquad\quad\qquad\quad\,\,\,
$$